# Is there any aug that increase the reserve energy?

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

Even if Biocells are plentyful, and can be made from scraps, I d rather use my scrap for something else, and spare my Biocell for item to power up.

Which mean I am on my reserve for the majority of my time, waiting for it to recharge or other.

Is there any way to increase the reserve part?
Human Revolution had one wich increased it to two "batteries" that I got as soon as possible, I'd like to do the same in Mankind Divided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "reserve energy" you mean the portion of your energy bar that always recharges, then no.  It cannot be increased in Mankind Divided.

Also, you are misremembering Human Revolution; there is [no augmentation](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Sarif_Series_8_Energy_Converter) in that game that increases the reserve energy either.

There are augmentations in both games that

1. increase the total size of the energy bar
2. reduce the time you have to wait before energy begins recharging
3. increase the speed at which energy recharges

Note that in Mankind Divided's Breach Mode you can indeed increase your reserve energy from 30 units to 45 units and then 60 units.

Comment: Right, seems I misinterpreted my memory of having two energy bars. Thanks a lot.

Comment: While you're correct that HR doesn't have an augmentation increasing reserve energy, energy will regenerate up to two cells on easy and normal difficulties in the Director's Cut version, which is probably what the asker remembered.